# Duplicate contacts are listed while reading device contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to read contacts from device. I am getting the list of device contacts , but the problem is most of them are duplicates. But in my default contacts app those duplicates are not there. Right now it is returning around `1150` contacts from device out of that around `602` are duplicates (when I checked the result using log), but my default contacts App is not showing this duplicates. This is my code

```
private void readPhoneContacts(Context context) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        HashMap<String, Contact> mContactListItems = new HashMap<>();
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                String image_uri = "";
                String phoneNumber = "";
                String name = "";
                String emailId = null;
                int image_urlCursorIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI);
                if (!cursor.isNull(image_urlCursorIndex)) {
                    image_uri = cursor.getString(image_urlCursorIndex);
                }
                int phoneNumberCursorIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                if (!cursor.isNull(phoneNumberCursorIndex)) {
                    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberCursorIndex);
                }
                int nameCursorIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (!cursor.isNull(nameCursorIndex)) {
                    name = cursor.getString(nameCursorIndex);
                }
                emailId = cursor.getString(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME);
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setName(name);
                contact.setEmailId(emailId);
                contact.setMobileNumber(phoneNumber);
                contact.setId(key);
                key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                if (image_uri != null && !image_uri.isEmpty()) {
                    contact.setHasLocalContactImage(true);
                    contact.setDeviceContactImageUri(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                }
                mContactListItems.put(String.valueOf(key), contact);

            }
            cursor.close();


        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    } catch (SecurityException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

What I want to get is `Id` , `Name` , `Phone number` , `Email Id` of all contacts from device. Also it should list all types of phone and email (home , office etc). Is there any way to avoid duplicates and get these data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using Phone.CONTENT_URI so you will not get email info as that uri doesnot store it

Comment: this link will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471850/how-to-get-all-contacts-first-name-last-name-email-phone-number-etc-without?rq=1